# View sound waves while recording audio in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to display sound waves while recording audio in Flutter. I have attached a photo of what I want to do in the photo below. I couldn't find any package about it. Can you help me?[image]

Comment: Try this one https://softans.com/view-sound-waves-while-recording-audio-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

You may try with any of these plugins

https://pub.dev/packages/audio_waveforms

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_audio_waveforms

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).